# Draft question: Are there for sources in Prague that have hand-held, printed maps?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to pose this question, not as a canonical, but rather one that adds to TSE content. It's meant to solicit input from any and all users and, in particular, @JonathanReez should it not distract from mod (and work/life) duties. Depending on the feedback, it may be useful to ask a similar question about other cities/locations (e.g., London, Paris, Tokyo, Amsterdam).

---

**Question**: Are there for sources in Prague that have hand-held, printed maps?

For my bucket-list trip to Prague/Praha and with an architectural history background, I want to make the most of my time in this City of a Thousand Spires.

I prefer to wander throughout a city, get its sense of place, feel its soul and its history. My navigational gene wants to orient me, and let me understand through the use of with maps and street guides.

And I would like to do it without digital assistance, as it narrows my focus to an app on a mobile device. While I do plan to use an app, I'd like to have printed versions of good walking and transportation maps, and am especially interested in what might be obtainable locally.

Are there for sources in Prague that have hand-held, printed maps? If available, it would be useful to have sources for printed guides/maps of transit options, both under and above ground and those that indicate taxi stands. It would be handy, although not a requisite, to find maps that can be mounted on a bicycle/scooter to navigate as you go.

And, as a side note, on return home, the printed map is very useful in identifying the thousands of images taken.

Comment: I will put a bounty on it for sure!

Comment: Be aware that this will take lots of time to prepare. Please expect a reply within a month. In the meantime I will start collecting my findings in a community wiki

Comment: @JonathanReez if it's not good timing, I apologize.

Comment: Well, for a proper answer I will need to visit several book stores, tourist centers, check online, etc. It will take some time. Perfectly good timing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there for sources in Prague that have hand-held, printed maps?

Maps are easy to obtain in Prague, no matter how you come to the country.

**Airport**: A free map is available at the airport's public transport information kiosks.

[image]

**Train station**: The main train station likewise gives out free maps at the public transport information counters.

[image]

**City center**: The city's official Visitor Center gives out free maps on **Rytirska 12** (Staromestske Namesti).

[image]

**Book stores**: any large bookstore (e.g. **Neoluxor** on Vaclavske Namesti) sells maps of various resolutions. You can usually get maps for both Prague and the entire Czech Republic, as well as various surrounding countries.

> If available, it would be useful to have sources for printed guides/maps of transit options, both under and above ground

Every map I've seen has the public transport options displayed, although some lack the bus stops.

> and those that indicate taxi stands

While some maps may display those, I advise you against ever taking a taxi from an official taxi stand, as that's where most tourists get ripped off. There's even a notorious [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eccBS7mDd2o) where a guy pretends to be a tourist and takes numerous official taxis.

> to find maps that can be mounted on a bicycle/scooter to navigate as you go.

I haven't seen those on sale, but perhaps try your luck at the bike rentals.

Comment: Fantastický ...

Comment: +1, let's do it